# foreach() table with empty space?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have following PHP code contain 2 foreachs

```
<div class="box">           
    <?php
    $category = ORM::for_table('cattable')->order_by_asc('order')->find_many();
    foreach ($category as $cat):
    $links = ORM::for_table('linktable')->order_by_asc('name')->where('idcat', $cat->id)->find_many();
    ?>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" >
        <table class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <td><?php echo $cat->name?></td>
                </tr>     
            </thead>

        <?php foreach ($links as $link): ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                    <td><?php echo $link->name?></td>                                           
                </tr>                                       
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach;

        foreach ($links as $link): ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                    <?php if($link->main==7)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <td><?php echo $link->name?></td>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>                              
                </tr>                                       
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
</div>
```

The problem is, that i do have many many white spaces and the tables arent shown like i want ..

i work with Col-lg-12 and i want to let all tables beeing shown like this: [image: img1]

but its shown like this:
[image: img2]
[image: img3]

also i have tons of empty   entries

Edit :

```
                        ?><?php foreach ($categorie as $cat):
                        $links = ORM::for_table('linktable')->order_by_asc('name')->where('idcat', $cat->id)->limit(10)->find_many();
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>    
                                    <td>
                                    <b>test</b>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>     
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($links as $link): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>test</td>                                                               
                                </tr>                                       
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This makes no difference (still empty spaces):

[image: img4]

Comment: So basically, you want to get rid of the empty values from the table? I can't look at your images as they are blocked on my current network. You should state explicitly in your question what you are trying to do.

Comment: not really sure what your problem is, but maybe just remove the additional `<tbody>`? move them outside the `foreach`s (both)  so that you only have one of them

Comment: _"i work with Col-lg-12"_ - you actually work with `col-lg-2`

Comment: the whole is col-lg-12 and the table get lg-2 as i want to have 6 each "line"

Comment: I think you'd better achieve what you want with a `ul` than with `cols`

Comment: yes, the previous version was with **ul** which working perfectly, but i would like to know how to let it work with **col** ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you  get different number of links from the database for each category, that causes the empty spaces. Try to echo the number of links you get by category:

```
                        ?><?php foreach ($categorie as $cat):
                    $links = ORM::for_table('linktable')->order_by_asc('name')->where('idcat', $cat->id)->limit(10)->find_many();
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>    
                                <td>
                                <b>test</b>
                                // Print the number of links by category
                                <?php echo count($links); ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>     
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($links as $link): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>test</td>                                                               
                            </tr>                                       
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: yeah i do know this :)
or do i misunderstand you ?

but i want the tables ordering directly under the next table https://i.imgur.com/Zkfulbb.png

Comment: Oh, I see sorry for misunderstanding your question. Now it is clear what you want to achieve. I am not an expert in CSS, but I don't think it is possible. Anyway I will let the CSS gurus have their say...